# Barely or Hardly or Scarcely

Tags: word-choice

I came across these sentences in Oxford Dictionary where [it](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/barely) says we can say the sentence 1 but not 2. Sentence 3 was written by me in order to compare.

> She hardly (ever) sees her parents these days.
>
> She barely sees her parents these days.
>
> She scarcely sees her parents these days.

I'd like to ask why. My understanding is that the second sentence implies that as if there is a physical obstacle between ( the girl and her parents) them like maybe a long and wide walls so it does not make sense.

I'd like to compare two these sentences so as to make sure I got them right.

For example :

> They hardly do exercise.

( what is your first impression? For example because they don't have time to do exercise etc.)

> They barely do exercise

( If this sentence makes a sense ,what is your first impression? Could you infer from the sentence that they cannot do exercise even though they want because there is a physical problem with their bodies)

Comment: Check out this NGram, which shows a significant change in usage over time for AmE. (note that this is overall use, not use in this particular context). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_PRON_+barely%2C_PRON_+hardly%2C_PRON_+scarcely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_PRON_%20barely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_PRON_%20hardly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_PRON_%20scarcely%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Why do you think the dictionary says you can't use *barely*?  It's an adverb - it modifies how she sees her parents - and it means "in a way that almost does not happen or exist".  So it means that she almost does not see her parents at all.

Answer (score 3):

According to the source you provided

> “Hardly” and “scarcely” can be used to mean “almost never,” but “barely” is not used in this way:
>
> - She hardly (ever) sees her parents these days.
> - <s>She barely sees her parents these days.</s>

“barely” doesn't convey the aforesaid meaning “hardly” does.

Your interpretation isn't quite lucid to me, but I think it's close to mine; i.e. “to barely see someone” means “to not be able to see someone clearly”, as if the view is obstructed in some way, or similar -- compared to the intended meaning “to hardly ever see someone”.

In the second part, I have the impression that your understanding is perfunctory. Firstly, the idiom “do exercise” doesn't strike me as common but I maintain it's grammatical.

Anyhow, my interpretation of your first example is “they seldom do the exercise”. Other meanings could be assigned as well. I interpret the second sentence as “they do the exercise with difficulty or struggle to complete it”.

Answer (score 3):

The three adverbs are largely interchangeable in these examples, but not their range of usage is not necessarily 100% identical in all cases.

In the first set, I would naturally interpret all three sentences to mean that there tend to be long time intervals between visits with her parents.  Remarks:

- *Hardly ever* and *scarcely* are synonymous, and unambiguously mean long time intervals between visits.
- *Barely* could lead to a different interpretation — one of degree, rather than frequency: *Her macular degeneration has gotten so bad, she barely recognizes her parents' faces these days.*  Though one must admit that some ambiguity is possible here, I would still tend to go with the "infrequent visits" interpretation, mainly because it would be odd to single out her parents if her eyesight is failing.
- *Hardly ever* works better than *hardly* to convey that meaning, especially since *ever* helps to reinforce the "infrequent" over the "to a small degree" interpretation.

Based on similar principles, I would say that

- *They barely do exercise* probably means "to a low degree", something like *They barely do exercise — all they do is mall walking.*  "Low degree" may or may not also imply low frequency.
- *They hardly do exercise* is awkward and ambiguous.  I'd recommend saying either *They hardly ever exercise* (infrequent) or *What they do can hardly be called exercise* (not really qualifying as exercise).

Answer (score 1):

The choice of adverb depends to some extent on the sentence (YMMV), but it doesn't work the other way round: the adverb alone does not really give you enough information to work out the reason why they don't do much exercise.

In typical usage, you would not say

> They hardly do exercise.

You would add information to explain what exactly you mean:

> They **can** hardly do exercise - ability- they find it difficult
>
> They hardly **ever** do exercise - they exercise infrequently
>
> They hardly do **any** exercise [**at all**] - they don't do very much exercise